# Save scroll position on back navigation : Cordova iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, angularjs, cordova

Framework and Libs used : Cordova, AngularJS

How do I maintain scroll position on a back button press ?

I initially store the position in a service object :

```
var page_data  = {
  page : $location.path,
  scrollpos : scrollpos // page.scrollTop()
};
```

then when I returned to the page  I scroll to the last scroll position saved :

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {

  $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop:  page_data.scrollpos},"fast");

  //tried $(page_ele).scrollTop(page_data.scrollpos) but that didn't work iOS
});
```

If I am navigating across several sub levels of pages , I push the page_data object into a stack and pop() it off as needed.

This works , but not 100% of the time because of slow rendering, can you guys offer a better and more robust solution ?